# How to change the CSS only for Myaccount page title?

Tags: magento2, phtml, myaccount

I want to change the `CSS` only for the title of My Account page.

[image]

I have added my custom class into the file `title.phtml` at the path `module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html`

But it affects all the page title.

How to resolve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Use body class customer_accout as a parent and add your CSS in title class. customer_account class only available in the customer_account pages. Please confirm the body class before applying in the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add CSS only for my account page title then you can add below css

```
.account.customer-account-index .page-title{
    /*css code write here*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's works great!!

Comment: Approve my answer if this will work for you. Welcome

Comment: Like .account, is there any common class name for login container?