# Magento 2 How to display Customer-Welcome in header link?

Tags: layout, magento2.3, phtml, headerlink

In the header links, I don't have "customer-welcome" on my website. Below is the screenshot taken from demo site. Please have a look at it.

[image]

How can display the customer welcome on my website?

Below is the code I'm having in header.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 */
$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
?>
<?php switch ($block->getShowPart()):
    case 'welcome': ?>
        <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
            <span class="logged-in" data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().fullname)">
            </span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
            <span class="not-logged-in" data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>"'></span>
            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('header.additional') ?>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </li>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php break; ?>

    <?php case 'other': ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    <?php break; ?>

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

[image]

**default.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="default_head_blocks" />
   <body>
      <!--<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>

      <referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>-->
       <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>
       <!-- <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />-->
         <referenceBlock name="company.link" remove="true" />


      <!--<referenceBlock name="header-wrapper" remove="true" />-->
      <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
      <move element="logo" destination="mycustom3.div" before="-" />
       <move element="header.panel.wrapper" destination="mycustom3.div" after="logo" />
      <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="mycustom3.div" after="header.panel.wrapper" />
      <move element="top.search" destination="mycustom4.div" before="-" />
      <move element="top.links" destination="mycustom4.div" after="top.search" />
      <!--<move element="header-wrapper" destination="mycustom4.div" after="top.search" />-->
      <move element="minicart" destination="mycustom4.div" after="header-wrapper" />
      <move element="mycustom4.div" destination="mycustom3.div" after="catalog.topnav" />

      <referenceContainer name="header.container">
         <container name="mycustom3.div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header" />
         <container name="mycustom4.div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="search-outer" />
      </referenceContainer>







      <referenceContainer name="footer-container" htmlClass="site_footer_wrap scheme_dark">
         <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="butterflyfooter" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer.phtml" />
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml" />
            <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true" />
         </container>
      </referenceContainer>


   </body>
</page>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You want to display message here, Right ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14PqZoRFCwroVgEJKrN08mzaBgsS0ckWA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Kindly share the header.phtml file of your theme.

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, After the greeting message, I want to display it. Please refer the attached image at question

Comment: @Sumit, I have included the header.phtml code in question

Comment: Have you tried the code I've added in my answer?

Comment: When do you want to show it? While the customer is logged in or when? Because if you want to display it all the time.... simply go add it in phtml file. `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml`

Comment: I want to show it after the customer logged in

Comment: @Siva for that you will need to use session.

Comment: @Zeeshan, its default function in function, right?

Comment: You can use this link for the session.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252698/how-to-hide-a-div-in-phtml-if-a-customer-is-logged-in-magento-2

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, Have you got any idea?

Comment: @Siva, Still I'm not clear with your requirements. I think you are not getting that sign in and welcome Siva text there. Am I right ?

Comment: I'm getting sign in and welcome Siva but not getting the dropdown which have links to My Account, My wishlist and sign out. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, Now I got what you are saying. Give me few mins, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks, please see the question, there I have added the screenshot marked which is missing on my site.

Comment: Yes, Now I got what you want there. Can you please let me know you have moved that link in any other section ?

Comment: I'm not sure, what I'm missing. I have included the code header.phtml as well in the question

Comment: Can you please give me what you're getting there in your custom theme ? So I'll suggest you something there. I believe you've moved header.links block somewhere and that is creating that issue.

Comment: I think you've added something like this.. ** <move element="top.links" destination="somewhere" before="some-element" />**. If yes then I can help you.

Comment: I just need top.links this line which you've added in your **default.xml**.

Comment: I have checked the default.xml file and here's the top.links element: <move element="top.links" destination="mycustom4.div" after="top.search" />

Comment: I have added the complete default.xml in question. Please help me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100134/discussion-on-question-by-siva-magento-2-how-to-display-customer-welcome-in-head).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your `default.xml` with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="default_head_blocks" />
   <body>
      <!--<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
      <referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>-->
       <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>
       <!-- <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />-->
         <referenceBlock name="company.link" remove="true" />
      <!--<referenceBlock name="header-wrapper" remove="true" />-->
      <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
      <move element="logo" destination="mycustom3.div" before="-" />
       <move element="header.panel.wrapper" destination="mycustom3.div" after="logo" />
      <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="mycustom3.div" after="header.panel.wrapper" />
      <move element="top.search" destination="mycustom4.div" before="-" />
      <move element="header.links" destination="mycustom4.div" after="top.search" />
      <!--<move element="header-wrapper" destination="mycustom4.div" after="top.search" />-->
      <move element="minicart" destination="mycustom4.div" after="header-wrapper" />
      <move element="mycustom4.div" destination="mycustom3.div" after="catalog.topnav" />

      <referenceContainer name="header.container">
         <container name="mycustom3.div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header" />
         <container name="mycustom4.div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="search-outer" />
      </referenceContainer>

      <referenceContainer name="footer-container" htmlClass="site_footer_wrap scheme_dark">
         <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="butterflyfooter" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer.phtml" />
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml" />
            <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true" />
         </container>
      </referenceContainer>

   </body>
</page>
```

I've changed this line here

```
<move element="top.links" destination="mycustom4.div" after="top.search" />
```

Instead of **top.links** you need to move **header.links** there like...

```
<move element="header.links" destination="mycustom4.div" after="top.search" />
```

After adding this please add below line in your `CSS`

```
.customer-welcome .action.switch { color: #111 !important; }
```

Now please run below commands in your CLI

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

That's it. Then you need to make some CSS changes there and it will work as per your requirements.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Is above solution works for you @Siva ?

Comment: Yes, I have just updated your code to my default.xml and see the customer menu is displaying when I make some css changes. Still working and let you know if I have any queries. Thanks!!

Comment: You can approve my answer. Thnaks :) Happy to help you Buddy!

Comment: Approved. Thanks. I have a query, can you please check my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293114/how-to-change-the-css-only-for-myaccount-page-title like .account css class, is there any specific class name for login?

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to solve it myself

Comment: Okay great!!! :)

Comment: One question. In demo site, I can see My account link is displaying in customer dropdown menu by default. But my case, its not displaying. Do I need to add it via layout.xml file.

Comment: That is not showing to you because you've removed that in default.xml file using this line.. **<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>**. Please comment this line and then check it will work.

Comment: If it works then let me know.

Comment: You're right. Its my mistake, I have removed the My account link. Now it works great

Comment: Okay Great!! :)